# Finding the end of the video in android

Tags: android, video-processing

I am new to the android. I want to find the end of the video.I am using VideoView to play the video in android.Now the requirement is,"After completing the playing the video in videoview, it automatically invoke the another Activity"
 How can I achieve this requirement in android?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the API.  [setOnCompletionListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/VideoView.html#setOnCompletionListener%28android.media.MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener%29).